# How to redefine a macro?

Tags: rust

In C++, you can undefine and redefine a macro.
For example, a common thing to do in video games is to redefine the logging macro to nothing in Release mode. This guarantees that the code completely disappears which helps with performance.

Is there a way to do a similar thing in Rust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you might do:

```
macro_rules! log_if_dbg {
    (...) => (if cfg!(debug_assertions) { /* do logging */ })
}
```

---

This is how  [the macro `debug_assert!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/macro.debug_assert!.html) is implemented. The doc says:

> Unlike assert!, debug_assert! statements are only enabled in non
>   optimized builds by default. An optimized build will omit all
>   debug_assert! statements unless -C debug-assertions is passed to the
>   compiler. This makes debug_assert! useful for checks that are too
>   expensive to be present in a release build but may be helpful during
>   development.

This is the same as your situation, only for assert, not logging. Looking at the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly//src/core/macros.rs.html#127-129):

```
macro_rules! debug_assert {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => (if cfg!(debug_assertions) { assert!($($arg)*); })
}
```

This has also been briefly discussed on the [Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/conditional-compilation-for-debug-release/1098/2), where the summary is that `cfg(debug_assertions)` is the way to check if we're in debug mode.

I have no idea how stable `cfg(debug_assertions)` is, however.

Answer (score 3):

You would use conditional compilation attributes:

```
#[cfg(feature = "debugging")]
macro_rules! log {
    () => { println!("Debugging") }
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "debugging"))]
macro_rules! log {
    () => { }
}

fn main() {
    log!();
}
```

Here, you can use [Cargo's "features"](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-[features]-section) to provide a compile-time argument that switches the implementation of debugging.

However, there's no *requirement* to use macros in this case:

```
#[cfg(feature = "debugging")]
fn log() { println!("Debugging") }

#[cfg(not(feature = "debugging"))]
fn log() {}

fn main() {
    log();
}
```

I'd trust pretty heavily in the optimizer to produce the same code in this case.

Comment: Nice approach, definitely cleaner and more robust that the `cfg(debug_assertions)` one.

Comment: @mdup and our answers can combine together, as well. You can use `cfg(debug_assertions)` where my answer uses `cfg(feature ...)`. With mine, there's a bit more extra work, but you can enable it separately from the release mode.