# How to check release / debug builds using cfg in Rust?

Tags: debugging, rust, preprocessor, rust-cargo

With the C pre-processor it's common to do,

```
#if defined(NDEBUG)
    // release build
#endif

#if defined(DEBUG)
    // debug build
#endif
```

Cargo's rough equivalents are:

- `cargo build --release` for release.
- `cargo build` for debug.

How would Rust's `#[cfg(...)]` attribute or `cfg!(...)` macro be used to do something similar?

I understand that Rust's pre-processor doesn't work like C's. I checked the documentation and [this page lists some attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#conditional-compilation). *(assuming this list is comprehensive)*

`debug_assertions` could be checked, but it may be misleading when used to check for the more general debugging case.

I'm not sure if this question should be related to Cargo or not.

Comment: @Shepmaster This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786738/how-to-redefine-a-macro/30787006?s=2%7C2.4527).

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can use [`debug_assertions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#debug_assertions) as the appropriate configuration flag. It works with both [`#[cfg(...)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) attributes and the [`cfg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html) macro:

```
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
fn example() {
    println!("Debugging enabled");
}

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
fn example() {
    println!("Debugging disabled");
}

fn main() {
    if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
        println!("Debugging enabled");
    } else {
        println!("Debugging disabled");
    }

    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    println!("Debugging enabled");

    #[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
    println!("Debugging disabled");

    example();
}
```

This configuration flag was named as a correct way to do this in [this discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/conditional-compilation-for-debug-release/1098/3). There is no more suitable built-in condition for now.

From the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html):

> `debug_assertions` - Enabled by default when compiling without
> optimizations. This can be used to enable extra debugging code in
> development but not in production. For example, it controls the
> behavior of the standard library's `debug_assert!` macro.

An alternative, slightly more complicated way, is to use `#[cfg(feature = "debug")]` and create a build script that enables a "debug" feature for your crate, as shown [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/conditional-compilation-for-debug-release/1098/7).

Comment: Just for the record, this doesn't work in build scripts. Just finding this out for myself so thought I'd share.

Comment: if it's `#[cfg(debug_assertions)]` instead of `#[cfg(debug_assertions)] {...}`, there'll be `error[E0658]: attributes on expressions are experimental` and `error: removing an expression is not supported in this position`. Rust 1.42.0

Comment: Also for the record, this doesn't work inside doc tests, since rustdoc seems to always set `debug_assertions` to true, even if you run `cargo test --release --doc`. This is issue #6570 in the cargo repo.