# Alternatives to panic!() and expect() for --release?

Tags: rust, panic

In development, my code uses `.expect()` and `panic!()` to handle fatal errors.

Their behaviour is exactly what I need *during development*.

When I compile with `--release`, I was hoping that their output would become more succinct.

i.e. This code:

```
let mut file_a = OpenOptions::new().write(true)
                                   .read(true)
                                   .open(args.file_a).expect("foo bar");
```

generates:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'foo bar: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/bin/vsapply.rs:131:59
```

When I would prefer just:

```
foo bar: No such file or directory
```

when compiled with `--release`.

Is there already a way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

One option you have available to you is, rather than flatly panicking, instead printing information to stderr by using `eprintln!()` and exiting with a non-zero error code.

```
use std::process;

fn main() -> {
    // some terrible state
    eprintln!("foo bar: No such file or directory.");
    process::exit(1);
}
```

This has a couple of benefits:

- Printing to stderr ensures that your error message isn't instead directed to some output file (e.g. `foo --option arg1 arg2 > output.txt`).
- A program calling your program can interpret a non-zero error code as an indication of failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Every second or third line of my code is an `unwrap()` or `expect()`.  Checking each condition manually would be too verbose and make the code unreadable.  Your point about stderr is important - I'll use the answer from @akihito-kirisaki with `eprintln!()`.

Comment: This follow https://clig.dev/ command line guidelines and I like it

Answer (score 4):

Combination of [std::panic::set_hook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html) and [#[cfg(debug_assertions)]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204908/how-to-check-release-debug-builds-using-cfg-in-rust) soleves the problem.

```
use std::panic;

fn main() {
    #[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(|panic_info| {
        if let Some(s) = panic_info.payload().downcast_ref::<&str>() {
            println!("panic occurred: {:?}", s);
        } else {
            println!("panic occurred");
        }
    }));
    println!("Hello, world!");
    panic!("nyaan");
}
```

When exec `cargo run`, output is:

```
Hello, world!
thread 'main' panicked at 'nyaan', src\main.rs:14:5
```

When `cargo run --release`:

```
Hello, world!
panic occurred: "nyaan"
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  With `--release` the hook code is called, but the extra information is not printed.  e.g. without `--release` I get `thread 'main' panicked at 'This delta expects file_b to be 43999 bytes long, not 44020 bytes.', src/bin/vsapply.rs:109:9
note: run with 'RUST_BACKTRACE=1' environment variable to display a backtrace` but with `--release` I just get `panic occurred`.  (The calling code is `panic!("This delta expects file_b to be {:?} bytes long, not {:?} bytes.", len, blen);`.)

Comment: It seems good to keep default `panic!` with `take_hook` and call it in custom `panic!`. https://www.ncaq.net/2019/07/11/18/18/12/